# How to update Spring Security Management Console?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have a User entity and apart from default fields/methods (I took the whole content from grails docs) I added fields like address, number etc. (Strings).

Now I rebuilded the whole project, deployed and I still don't see those in Spring Security Management Console.

How to force Spring Security Management Console to show my custom User fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume a couple of things when authoring this answer:

1. What you meant by the first part of the question is that you have added fields to the User domain class that was generated by the Spring Security Plugin
2. You are speaking of the Spring Security UI Plugin when you say "Management Console"

With those two assumptions in mind, you need to take a look at [this documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/guide/customization.html). Simply adding the fields to the Domain class will not affect the UI plugin, as the plugin has pre-defined views and controllers for dealing with the default fields in the domain object.

You need to "override" these views and controllers to support your new fields. From the sounds of it, running this script should "extract" the views and controller you need:

`grails s2ui-override user <controller_package>`

Where the controller_package is the package you would like the new UserController class to be a part of.